# One of my doubt about ''of late''

Tags: meaning

> Lidia Ivanovna's dress had cost her great pains, as indeed all her dresses had done of late.

I am guessing between 2 meanings of the last part of sentence: all her dresses cost her great pains or lately her dresses cost her great pains.

Could you tell me which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Of late** is another way of saying **lately** or **recently**.

The sentence is saying that all her recent dresses had cost her great pains.

I don't know the context but the suggestion is that she had put a great deal of effort either into making the dresses or acquiring them; or perhaps she'd had to make painful sacrifices in order to get them.